# Listening to window events on Typescript (angular2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I'm trying to listen to events on `window` from within an angular2 application, written in typescript. I'm also using jquery (added via `typings`).

The events I want to listen to are added by an external lib which I add within `<script>` tags on index.html. If I add a listener on `window` on index.html, it works ok:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://my-host/front-libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://my-host/my-external-lib.min.js"></script>
    <title>Angular 2 App | ng2-webpack</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
    <script>
      // this works!!
      $(window).on('authenticatedUser', function(e) {
        console.log('ok.');
      });
    </script>
    <base href="/">
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

But if I try to listen to those same events from within my angular2 app, it doesn't:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

import { ApiService } from './shared';

import '../style/app.scss';


/*
 * App Component
 * Top Level Component
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', // <my-app></my-app>
  providers: [ApiService],
  directives: [...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  url = 'https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack';

  ngOnInit(){


   // this doesn't seem to work. I never get notified about 
   // 'authenticatedUser' events on `window`
   $((<any>window)).on('authenticatedUser', function(e) {
     console.log('fuuuu');
   });


   // this triggers events on `window`
   (<any>window).myNamespace.start({
      scopeName: null,
      canClose: false,
      returnUrl: 'http://localhost:8080/loggedIn'
    });
  }

  constructor(private api: ApiService) { }
}
```

Is this the correct way to attach event handlers to window from within an angular2 app? I feel there must be a better way.

Comment: did you try HostListener ??

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the correct way to attach event handlers to window from within an angular2 app

If it works in JavaScript it should work in TypeScript. So what I am about to show you will not fix that.

However don't listen to window events like that as angular recommends something like

```
host: {
    '(window:resize)': 'onResize($event)'
}
```